# Symfony3 link to change locale

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a link which will change the `locale` in the code below.

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/changelanguage", defaults={"_locale" = "eu"}, name="changelanguage")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function changelanguageAction(Request $request) {


    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    if ($locale == "eu") {
        $request->setLocale('es');
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', 'es');
    } else {
        $request->setLocale('eu');
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', 'eu');
    }

    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));

}
```

then, in my twig base view I'm using this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">        
    <li><a href="#">{{ app.request.locale }}</a></li>
    {% if  app.request.locale == "eu"%}
        <li><a href="{{ path('changelanguage', {'_locale':'es'}) }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/app/img/espanol.png') }}" alt="Castellano"> Castellano</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ path('changelanguage', {'_locale':'eu'}) }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/app/img/euskara.png') }}" alt="Euskaraz"> Euskara</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    <li>&nbspp;</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that it keeps telling me that `app.request.locale` is always `'eu'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm confused by your code. Are you trying to force "es"?

Comment: I want to change between es and eu locales. For example, show an index page with 'es' locale and with a link with will render the same page but changing the user locale and remain.

Answer (score 1):

Add default language to user entity and then create Request Listener that check the default language for the user and change it...

This work for me

**Create a listener**

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class LanguageListener
{
    private $token_storage;

    private $securityContext;

    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $containerInterface)
    {
        $this->container = $containerInterface;
        $this->securityContext = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
        $this->token_storage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');;

    }

    public function setLocale(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }


        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            $userLocale = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()
                ->getCustomer()->getDefaultCodeLanguage();

            if ($userLocale) {
                $request = $event->getRequest();
                $request->setLocale($userLocale);
                $translator = $this->container->get('translator');
                $translator->setLocale($userLocale);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    language.kernel_request_listener:
        class: UserBundle\EventListener\LanguageListener
        arguments:
            - "@service_container"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocale }
```

Comment: it´s not working for me, it keeps in the same locale all the time